# replay().autoconnect() does not replay events

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm facing some issues with `replay().autoconnect()` operator combination.
Before I ask my question, let me share some knowledge I have regarding this operators. I have been following this [tutorial on multicasting](https://youtu.be/wxx9hEi_E8c?t=1464)

What I understood is

- `replay()` operator can re-emit the results of the observable when a new subscriber comes in, without re-executing the source observable (Helps during network calls)
- `autoconnect()` can turn the observable into a hot observable, so that even if all the subscribers leave and later a new subscriber comes in, the observable would still be active and re-emit the results via `replay()`

So, I found `replay().autoConnect()` combination would be apt for my network calls.

In my App, I use fragments all over, and in the `BaseFragment` I'm keeping a `Composite` disposable. All my disposables during the fragment lifecycle I keep on adding in the `CompositeDisposable` and in the `onDestroyView` event, I'm disposing the disposables, since I don't want to listen for observable emissions when the fragment is not visible.

I have a use-case where I make a network call in one fragment, say `FragmentA` and then go to `FragmentB` without killing `FragmentA` (I'm doing fragment replace). Later I can come back to `FragmentA`  from backstack.
When I move from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` obviously my observers will be disposed, but what I expect is, when I come back to `FragmentA` later, I should get the old network call results immediately since I'm using `replay().autoConnect()` on the observable.

But instead some weird thing happens here, I can see the old observable is  still there, but it doesn't emit any values. 
If I change the `mCompositeDisposable.dispose();` to `onDestroy()` instead of `onDestroyView()` it works as expected

As per the tutorial, **autoconnect() doesn't terminate the observable even if all the observers leave**

But in my case, when all the observers leave and later new observer comes in, it doesn't emit only, and since it triggers the `doOnsubscribe()` all  I can see is an infinite loading dialog in the UI (since I'm showing loader on `doOnsubscribe`). I'm posting a sample code which exactly replicates my issue.

> BaseFragment.java

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{
private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable;
private ProgressDialog mProgressBar;

protected void addToDisposable(Disposable disposable) {
    if (mCompositeDisposable == null) mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (mCompositeDisposable != null) {
        mCompositeDisposable.dispose();
    }
}

public void showProgress(String message) {
    if (mProgressBar == null) {
        mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mProgressBar.setCancelable(false);
    }
    mProgressBar.setMessage(message);
    mProgressBar.show();
}

public void dismissProgress() {
    if (mProgressBar != null && mProgressBar.isShowing()) {
        mProgressBar.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    replaceFragment(new FragmentA());
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```

> FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends BaseFragment {
private TextView textView;
private Button button;
private static final String TAG = "FragmentA";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> ((MainActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment(new FragmentB()));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    DisposableObserver<List<String>> disposableObserver = Repository.getStringObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(strings -> dismissProgress())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> showProgress("Please wait"))
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<String> strings) {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String string : strings) {
                        stringBuilder.append(string).append("\n");
                    }
                    textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
                }
            });

    addToDisposable(disposableObserver);
  }
 }
```

> Repository.java

```
public class Repository {
static Observable<List<String>> listObservable;

public static Observable<List<String>> getStringObservable() {
    if (listObservable == null)
        listObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                strings.add("String " + i);

            }
            Thread.sleep(5000);// mocking network call
            return strings;
        }).replay(1).autoConnect();
    return listObservable;
 }
}
```

FragmentB code is not posted since its empty. Issue can be observed when pressing back from FragmentB.

Hope my issue is clear. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `replay().autoConnect()` here. You are disposing the composite which will then prevent any future observers from receiving data. use `clear()` instead.

Comment: thanks!!! it works fine. So `dispose` would terminate the source observable itself?

Comment: If not, what if I really want to terminate the hot observable at a later point of time

Comment: No. It disposes the consumers trying to consume `autoConnect`. Look for overloads of `autoConnect` to stop its source.